# Looking for a alternative to create a JSON object instead using Json.createObjectBuilder

Tags: java

Just for learn, I'm trying understand a better way to create a JSON response. I expect the following output on my request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/json
connection: close

{
  "status": "ok"
}
```

Using Java for this task (In this case Quarkus), I have the follow code:

```
package br.com.bb.feedback.Controller;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.Json;

@Path("/health-check")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HealthCheckController {
    @GET
    public Response check() {
        JsonObject health = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("status", "ok").build();

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(health).build();
    }
}
```

So, to build the entity object I use `Json.createObjectBuilder()`. Have a better way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps Gson Library.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by better.  There are lots of different JSON libraries for Java ... supporting a number of different models for generating and parsing JSON.  Many could be viewed as better than others, depending on the "goodness" criteria ... and your specific use-case.

Comment: For example, if your application's requests only return that response, the passing a literal string as the entity body would be the *most performant* solution.  (And have the least number of dependencies.)

Comment: But this question is perilously close to a "request for a software recommendation" which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" way is a matter of opinion, but there are easy to use *alternate* ways:

- Using a `Map`. In Java 9+, that's really easy:

  ```java
  @GET
  public Response check() {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                     .entity(Map.of("status", "ok"))
                     .build();
  }
  ```

  In Java 8 or earlier, it takes a bit extra:

  ```java
  @GET
  public Response check() {
      Map<String, String> health = new HashMap<>();
      health.put("status", "ok");
      return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(health).build();
  }
  ```
- Using a POJO:

  ```java
  @GET
  public Response check() {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                     .entity(new Health("ok"))
                     .build();
  }

  static final class Health {
      private String status;
      // constructors, getters, and setters here
  }
  ```